# Character clothes customization in VR with Unity 3D template

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Greetings everyone from Thailand! I'm a 3rd-year multimedia undergraduate student. Now, I'm working on a Metaverse project for my thesis.  I know how to do character customization for 3d games (reskin, color change, mesh renderer)

but I want to know if it would be the same thing for metaverse development also I want to have a mirror in my metaverse for users to see the result of clothes customization. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

While VR is a component of the Metaverse, the latter encompasses a broader concept of a collective virtual shared space that includes the sum of all virtual worlds, augmented reality, and the internet. I wouldn't use it interchangeably.

Given that VR uses 3D models, the experience with re-skinning logic in 3D programs that you mentioned is transferable. So, when applying custom clothes or models onto a VR body, you could use the built-in (or custom) inverse kinematics tools to reflect the player's movement and swap them out in the same fashion you mentioned.

For the mirror, look at [Render Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) as a simple solution; it effectively renders what a Camera sees, which can be limited to just the layer of your player if you'd like.

For specific code or implementation details, it would be helpful if you could provide more information or a particular snippet of code related to your customisation logic.